# webkit scrollbar css unsupported by ie

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For styling scrollbar (of `ul`) I have used css. `.requestType` is the class of `ul`.

css I used is -

```
.requestType{
height:600px;  overflow-y: scroll; }    

.requestType::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #F5F5F5; }

.requestType::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 5px;   background-color: #F5F5F5; }

.requestType::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-color: darkgray;   }

.list-group {
    display: flow-root; }
```

It works fine in chrome.

But in case of `IE` and `mozilla firefox` it applies simple scrollbar without styling it.

What should I do for styling scrollbar in `IE` AND `mozilla firefox` also.

```
 <ul class="list-group mb-3 requestType" id="requestType">

            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
              <div class="text-success">
                <label class="Request_type" for="radio4">abc
                  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="abc" id="radio4">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  <h5><small class="text-muted">Brief description</small></h5>
                </label>
              </div>

            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
              <div class="text-success">

                <label class="Request_type" for="radio6">xyz
                  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="xyz" id="radio6">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  <h5><small class="text-muted">Brief description</small></h5>
                </label>
              </div>

            </li>
```

Comment: First of all leave IE, It does not support most of the current technology since microsoft depricated it.

Comment: And please share the html you used

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of UX and UI! Browser Support Matrix's are great to have for such issues, you can use them to define *what* and *how* items are viewed when your application is viewed in different browsers - or devices such as IPad, Mobile etc.

You can provide else statements for views to then display a certain view if the user is viewing the site in chrome for example and another view for IE. This may be an option for you.

Alternatively, you could produce a stylesheet compatible with all browsers - here is a quick list of CSS properties not compatible with IE https://www.impressivewebs.com/10-useful-css-properties-not-supported-by-internet-explorer/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

IE and [Moziila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) just don't support it. The way to have a cool scrollbar is to use a library for the purpose, you can look up some jquery based plugging or npm package like this one [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar). The other way is to do one from scratch with vanilla js and some css (Keep in mind that all scroll involving action are taxing).